# Created Table showingup in Object explorer but not in sys.tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Recently I run into a scenario, where

1. I created a table in a database.
2. Refreshed the tables in Object explorer
3. Table appeared in the list
4. I used the query 'select * from sys.tables' and selected the database in dropdown list
5. Executed the query
6. Table NOT in the list

We are using SQL server 2008 R2 and this issue is observed on our clients machine. Sadly, I don't know much about the history of the database.

Has anyone seen this issue before. Any little help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Seems strange... are you sure you are running the queries `CREATE TABLE ...` and `select * from sys.tables` in the same database?

Comment: I know you mentioned that you selected the database from the dropdown list (I assume that you are using SSMS). Have you tried `USE …` as well?

Comment: This might help: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57826/system-table-missing-in-sql-server-2012

Comment: @mortb Thanks for the response. I tried everything on one database

Comment: @Manngo Many thanks for the response. I tried Use as well.

Comment: I may sound silly, I can create table twice. one is reflecting in object explorer ( management studio ) and the other is reflecting in sys.tables. I tried  'select * sys.databases' which is showing only one database.

Comment: In the words of IT Crowd, have you tried turning it off and on again? In this case, quit and restart SSMS, which is otherwise harmless. In desperation I would also consider restarting the database.

Comment: @Sharmila Also, is there a possibility that it’s a different schema?

Comment: We are trying to fix remotely on the clients database, as we are not able to replicate the issue on our databases. We literally copy-pasted the code.

Comment: Is it the same (that the new table does not show up) if you query the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` view instead of `sys.tables`?

Comment: Both INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES and sys.tables are in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the issue..

Issue is because we are using remote connections. It seems SQL query editor will remember the connection. So query editor is using one connection and Object explorer is using a different connection. They both are not pointing to the same server. 
So when we created a table using SSMS, then we can see the table created, but not the same when used with query editor. As both the servers has same databases we always thought that it's the same server.

To change the connection of query editor,  **Right click on the sql query editor -> Connections -> Change connection.**

With this we changed the connection of the query editor. And now both Object explorer and query editor are in sync, and we can see the table that is created.

Happy ending!!

@Mortb and @Manngo, once again many thanks for your contribution..